# date picker format wp7 showing time

Tags: windows-phone-7, time, datepicker

I want to change my date picker format in windows phone 7. I have changed it to {0:dd-MM-yyyy}
but I still get both date and time in the string and also the preceding zeroes are omitted.
like if I want a date like 03-11-1988 all I get is 3/11/1988 00:00 AM.

how do I correct this ?

this is my xaml

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Margin="261,463,0,0" x:Name="datePicker1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" ValueStringFormat="{}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
<toolkit:DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="261,558,0,0" x:Name="datePicker2" Height="77" VerticalAlignment="Top" ValueStringFormat="{}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
<toolkit:DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="261,648,0,0" x:Name="datePicker3" VerticalAlignment="Top" ValueStringFormat="{}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
```

Comment: Which version of the WP7 toolkit do you use? With the current August release your code works fine.

Comment: it works on screen.The display is correct only on the screen but the values returned are not correct.

Comment: For me the display is also correct after picking a different value. Do yoou mean this eith returned value? Or do you mean the string displayed in Visual Studio then showing the Value-property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am talking about the value property.

The display in the selector is correct.The value property is returning string in the form like **3/12/2011 00:00 AM**. although

```
String txtDate = Convert.ToString(txtDated.ToShortDateString());
```

removes **00:00AM** but the date is still **3/12/2011** format and i want **03-12-2011** for which i think the only solution is replacing / with - in the string.